# Insert or replace when column matches value

Tags: sqlite

I have the following table in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `gid` INT NOT NULL,
  `x` INT NOT NULL,
  `y` INT NOT NULL,
  `z` INT NOT NULL,
  `type` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ( `gid`, `x`, `y`, `z` ),
  UNIQUE INDEX myIndex(gid,(CASE WHEN `type` = '1' THEN `type` END))
);
```

The combination of gid, x, y, z is unique. There can be multiple rows with the same gid and type as long as the x/y/z values are different.

However, I want the combination of gid and a specific type value to be unique. For example, there can only be one row per gid = x with type = 1, but there can be multiple rows with gid = x and type = 2. I currently have the table above in MySQL, but I want to have a similar table in SQLite. What can I do to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0):

You need a [partial index](https://www.sqlite.org/partialindex.html):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX myIndex ON `test` (gid, type) WHERE type = 1;
```